# Use Javascript to change html button text and image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

if changing a button using javascript and I want to change just the text I can do this:

```
$('#btnTest').text(data.test-text + " : Test")
```

How do I amend that to change the button image also? had tried this but didn't work

```
$('#btnTest').text(data.test-text + " : Test" + <img src="~/assets/img/TestIcon.png" /> )
```

Comment: Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @Pointy said, use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/). Also:

- Fix your quotes in the `img` tag;
- `data.test-text` property name is probably invalid.

---

```
$('#btnTest').text(data.testText + " : Test" + '<img src="~/assets/img/TestIcon.png" />')
```